# PHP header('Location') redirect not working

Tags: php

I am working on a login script for my website and I can't use `header('Location: url');` I'm using a live server for my tests Here's my code

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: http://some-website.com/user/');
    exit();
}

...

?>
```

But Instead of redirecting me to the URL given above It just shows the blank page Looks like It's using `exit()` but not `header()` I'm pretty confused

Comment: So look at the response in your browsers network tools. What headers are being sent?

Comment: could you print some thing before the header and inside the if statement, i need to be sure your code come inside the if statement

Comment: is the session variable actually set?

Comment: Your header function doesn't have any problem. Remove your `if` statement and see if it works...

Comment: Do you have to use a fixed path or can it be relative? If the page is on your site try to use a relative path

Comment: Yes the session variable is set

Comment: I see the blank page after setting my session

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like your condition is not verified that's why you're getting a blank page, try to check if `$_SESSION` global variable contains `$_SESSION['username']` by adding before your `if` statement `var_dump($_SESSION)` then check out if 'username' is in it.

Comment: Well var_dump will just display what's in the $_SESSION global variable http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php, so you'll be able to check if $_SESSION['username'] is defined or not I mean if the username session has been initialized

Comment: It shows the username stored Inside the `$_SESSION` I think the problem Is with the `header()` as I usually experience problems with `header()`

Comment: Try to add these before your `ob_start`   `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`
`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` then let me know what errors are being displayed

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already fixed It by placing the `if()` statement and `header()` on top of everything and It worked Thank you again :)